# Changing line color below specific value in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I am trying to color the line below a specific value a certain color. I am using Chart.js v3.7.1

I have implemented the solution found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691397/1725871) with partial success...

[image: partial success]

```js
 let posColour= 'rgb(86,188,77)';
 let negColour= 'rgb(229,66,66)';
 let config = {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: tempData.sensorName,
                        data: data,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.9)',
                        borderColor: posColour,
                        pointRadius: false,
                        pointColor: '#3b8bba',
                        pointStrokeColor: posColour,
                        pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                        pointHighlightStroke: posColour,
                        segment: {
                            borderColor: (ctx2) => (ctx2.chart.data.datasets[0].data[ctx2.p0DataIndex] < 40 ? negColour : posColour)
                        }

                    }]
                }
                 /*  items below here are not necessary to reproduce the issue  */
                 ,
                options: {
                    reponsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                displayFormats: timeFormat,
                                format: 'day'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                major: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                maxTicksLimit: 15
                            },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Date'
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Temp (\u00b0C)'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                 /*  items above here are not necessary to reproduce the issue  */
            }
```

I am aware that I can do it very [simply with a fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52661923/1725871), but the visible impact of the inversed area chart is not the visual effect I am seeking.

I am looking for something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66943726/1725871), but I cannot get the last two lines to work (I am not familiar enough with ChartJS).

```js
let posColour= 'rgb(86,188,77)';
let negColour= 'rgb(229,66,66)';

plugins: [{
  beforeRender: (x, options) => {
    const c = x.chartArea; //tweaked for chart.js3 
    const dataset = x.data.datasets[0];
    const yScale = x.scales.y; //tweaked for chart.js3
    const yPos = yScale.getPixelForValue(40); //I want everything under 40 red, not 0 as the original answer...

    const gradientFill = c.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, c.height);
    gradientFill.addColorStop(0, posColour);
    gradientFill.addColorStop(yPos / c.height, posColour);
    gradientFill.addColorStop(yPos / c.height, negColour);
    gradientFill.addColorStop(1, negColour);

    //these two lines are the ones i can't figure out how to convert to chart.js3...
    const model = x.data.datasets[0]._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].dataset._model;
    model.borderColor = gradientFill;
  },
}];
```

[image: Not quite right]

Answer (score 4):

The solution provided by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289202/2358409) can easily be adapted to also work with Chart.js v3.7.1.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const threshold = 25;

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let yAxis = chart.scales.y;
      let yThreshold = yAxis.getPixelForValue(threshold);
      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yAxis.top, 0, yAxis.bottom);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'green');
      let offset = 1 / yAxis.bottom * yThreshold;
      gradient.addColorStop(offset, 'green');
      gradient.addColorStop(offset, 'red');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'red');
      chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = gradient;
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [32, 44, 29, 33, 18, 15, 30],
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: If I look that generated line, color change is not exactly where is should be. It is below given value. And in my adoption, there is even bigger difference. Can You explain why? How to fix it?

Comment: EDIT: Ah, I found correct offset calculation from Your linked topic.
`let offset = (yThreshold - yAxis.top) / (yAxis.bottom - yAxis.top);`

Answer (score 1):

I have made a detailed response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73164435/19373729) that can help you.

Here is the code:

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterLayout: chart => {
      let ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      let yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
      let yThresholdMax = yAxis.getPixelForValue(data.limits.max);  
      let yThresholdMin = yAxis.getPixelForValue(data.limits.min);  

      let offsetMax = 1 / yAxis.bottom * yThresholdMax; 
      let offsetMin= 1 / yAxis.bottom * yThresholdMin; 

      let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, yAxis.top, 0, yAxis.bottom);   
      
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red'); 
      gradient.addColorStop(offsetMax, 'darkred'); 
      gradient.addColorStop(offsetMax, 'blue'); 
      gradient.addColorStop(offsetMin, 'blue');
      gradient.addColorStop(offsetMin,'darkred');
      gradient.addColorStop(1,"red");           
      chart.data.datasets[0].borderColor = gradient;    
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
      ......
  },
    options: {
    ........
   }
});
```