# How can I set the colour of line segments below/above a threshold (y) value on a step line chart with Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using ChartJS 3.9.1.
I plot a step line chart of streak values like it is shown below.
[An example streak step line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qihGF.png)

I would like for this chart to display (y) values above 0 as green, and (y) values below 0 as red.

After searching SO, I found and tried the following solution:

```
const configuration = {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            //labels: Array.from({ length: xAxisLength }, (x, i) => i),
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: modeLabel,
                    data: streakVals,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    xAxisID: "x",
                    borderWidth: 6,
                    //borderColor: (ctx) => (ctx.parsed.y < 0 ? "rgba(255,0,0,0.95)" : "rgba(0,255,0,0.95)"),
                    borderColor: (ctx) => "rgba(0,255,0,0.95)",
                    segment: {
                        borderColor: (ctx) => (ctx.p0.parsed.y < 0 ? "rgba(255,0,0,0.95)" : "rgba(0,255,0,0.95)"),
                    }
                },
            ],
        },
...
```

However, that produces the following chart:
[Example step line chart with different colour segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuok0.png)

While I do understand why it did this, it's evidently not what I was hoping for. Essentially, I would like to be able to change the colour of the segment at a point between two data points or in other words, at a location where there is not a data point. For clarity, this is what I would like my chart to look like:
[Example step line chart- what I am hoping to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX08U.png)

Will I have to use a plugin? Or change my data structure to include (0,0) between each of my data points (though I would prefer to avoid this)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72229358/2358409

Comment: @uminder Yes, it does- thank you! I am new to SO, so I am unsure how to mark your comment as the accepted answer. If you can let me know, I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: Only answers can be accepted, comments unfortunately not. If a question has already an answer elsewhere, it should be marked as duplicate by providing the link to the that answer, then be closed. That's what I did just now (the question will however be effectively closed only when other users do the same). You could now upvote the original answer but only if you have at least 15 reputation points (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347).

Comment: @uminder Got it, thanks for your help!