# trying to change color of the line graph, two different colors for positive and negative values

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using the below code snippet but context.dataIndex is always undefined.which is what i believe might be causing the issue.
I am using an API to fetch data.

"chart.js": "^2.9.3","ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
Any help would be much appreciated, first time asking a question here.
Thanks!

```
lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] =[{ data: [], 
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
 
  borderColor: (context)=> {
    var index = context.dataIndex;
    console.log("index: "+context.dataIndex )
    var value = context.dataset.data[index];
    console.log("value: "+context.dataset.data )
    return value < 0 ? 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' :  // draw negative values in red
    'rgb(235,100,76)';
  },
  label: 'Net Amount' }];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916867/chart-js-line-different-fill-color-for-negative-point

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289202/2358409

Comment: @uminder unfortunately this is not working for me...let yAxis = myChart.options.scales["y-axis-0"]; is undefined for some reason

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691543/chartjs-how-can-i-get-different-color-fills-between-my-two-datasets-in-a-line-g/61695757#61695757